# powershell v2 datetime the ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss") has a bug

Tags: datetime, powershell

With powershell v2 I  read data from Sharepoint and write this data to Sql Server Tables. Al is fine but for the date time field I have a strange result :

For example the Sharepoint field value is : 30/01/2015 14:35:06
After I apply the ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss") method the result is : '20150130 14:01:06'
The value of minutes is 01 instead of 35 ???
Can someone tell me how to resolve this.
Thanks a lot.
Bachir

Comment: What type to you apply `ToString()` to? Can you provide us with a full code example?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution
Before using the ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss") method we have to call the Update() method.
Bachir

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem.
The solution is to use the ToString method for datetime variable like that:
$dateteimevalue.ToString("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss") with  "mm" lowercasehe for minute and not HH:MM:ss, because if we use uppercase MM for the minutes, it is interpreted as month by PowerShell.
Bachir